# Getting an app on two iPads in sync

Tags: ios, ipad, bluetooth, vnc

We are trying to figure out a way to get app on two iPads in sync.

So the use case would be like this:

We have two iPads, on each one is the app A running. User 1 is doing something on his iPad and this changes should be displayed on the iPad of the User 2.

Do you think a bluetooth(WiFi?) communication could work or should something like a VNC viewer be done?

cheers

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you only want to sync them on local wifi or bluetooth, without using the server, check out GameKit peer to peer. There's even [sample code](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#samplecode/GKTank/Introduction/Intro.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/DTS40008918) from Apple that shows you how to pair devices and communicate between them.